# compare a value to every pair of values in a pandas dataframe

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data frame with intervals like:

```
begin   end
  2       4 
  6       8
  9      11
```

I want to compare a value to each of such pair of interval. If that value is in the range of any interval, it will be 'yes', else it will be 'no'.

For example: x = 3 => yes (because 2<x<4), x=5 => no

I currently do this with a nested loop through each value of x and each the interval. But I have multiple values of x and multiple intervals, so the nested loop is really slow. Is there any way I can do this efficiently without a loop? Thank you!

Comment: How many intervals and how many values of x do you have?

Answer (score 0):

You can use broadcasting to speed up the comparisons:

```py
def check_intervals(x):
     if any((intervals.begin < x) & (x < intervals.end)):
         return 'yes'
     else:
         return 'no'
 
>>> intervals = pd.DataFrame({'begin': [2, 6, 9], 'end': [4, 8, 11]})
>>> intervals
   begin  end
0      2    4
1      6    8
2      9   11
>>> check_intervals(3)
'yes'
>>> values = [3, 5, 10, 11]
>>> [check_intervals(x) for x in values]
['yes', 'no', 'yes', 'no']
```

That should be fast enough for a few thousand comparisons per second.

Answer (score 0):

Not sure this improves efficiency at all, but you could create a column of whether your value falls in the interval like so,

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'a':[2, 6, 9], 'b':[4, 8, 11]})
df['a'] = df['a'].astype(str)
df['b'] = df['b'].astype(str)
df['t'] = df['a'].str.cat(df['b'],sep=",")
```

```
def in_between(x, val):
    a, b = x.split(',')
    if val > int(a) and val < int(b):
        return 'yes'
    else:
        return 'no'

val = 3
df['bw'] = df['t'].map(lambda x: in_between(x, val))
df
```

Answer (score 0):

Here is another take on it just for the sake of benchmarking, that relies only on `numpy` which probably makes it the fastest option at the expense of taking up more memory. On my machine, this takes around 2 seconds to evaluate 10000 values and 10000 intervals.

```
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd

N = 10
values = np.random.randn(N) * N # Your x values

df = pd.DataFrame({"begin": [2, 6, 9], 
                   "end": [4, 8, 11]})
data = df.to_numpy()

begin = data[:, 0] < values[np.newaxis].T
end = values[np.newaxis].T < data[:, 1]
answer = np.stack((begin, end), axis=-1)
answer = answer.all(axis=-1).any(axis=-1)
```

Where `answer` is of the same shape as `values`. Afterwards, you can just do a simple replacement of `True` and `False` to `yes` and `no`, respectively.